# Probability density function of harmonic oscillation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, physics

This is within the domain of physics, but I am interested in this problem from a mathematical / probability perspective.

Suppose a mass on a spring is pulled to a length A and released. The mass undergoes harmonic oscillation. I know that the motion is of the form:

$$x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi) $$

Now I am interested in finding the probability density function of the position $x$ at time $t$, assuming time is a random variable uniformly distributed along the period of oscillation. How can this be done, given the above formula?

Comment: The time spent in an (infinitesimal) interval is inversely proportional to the speed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution

Answer (score 2):

Let $Τ$ be a uniform random variable on $\left[0,\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right]$ that describes time. Then $F_T(t)=\frac{ωt}{2\pi}=ft$, where $f$ is the oscilation's frequency. Now, let:

$$X=A\cos(ωT+\phi)$$

be the random varoalbe describing $x$ in terms of $T$. We have:

$$\begin{align}
F_X(x)&=P(X≤x)=P(A\cos(ωT+\phi)\leq x)=P\left(\cos(ωT+\phi)\leq \frac{x}{A}\right)=\\
&=P\left(\arccos\frac{x}{A}\leqωT+\phi\leq 2\pi-\arccos\frac{x}{A}\right)=\\
&=P\left(\frac{\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\leq T\leq\frac{2\pi-\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\right)=\\
&=F_T\left(\frac{2\pi-\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\right)-F_T\left(\frac{\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\right).
\end{align}$$

Differentiating both sides, we get:

$$f_X(x)=f_T\left(\frac{\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\right)\frac{\left(-\arccos\frac{x}{A}\right)'}{\omega}-f_T\left(\frac{2\pi-\arccos\frac{x}{A}-\phi}{\omega}\right)\frac{\left(\arccos\frac{x}{A}\right)'}{\omega}.$$

Now, since $f_T(t)=f=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ and $\arccos'x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, we have:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{A\sqrt{1-x^2/A^2}}+\frac{1}{A\sqrt{1-x^2/A^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{πA \sqrt{1-x^2/A^2}},$$
or, pushing $A$ into the root:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{A^2-x^2}},\ x\in(-A,A).$$

Note how nicely the probability is unaffected by angular velocity and initial phase ($\omega,\phi$), which is, intuitively, expected.

**Edit:** For @Keith McClary's confirmation, we can observe that:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\omega}{\pi |v(x)|},$$

where $v(x)$ is the object's velocity at position $x$.

Comment: Here,  $v(x)$ should be the *speed* (absolute value of the velocity) at position $x$. Because the velocity can be negative (and also, it's not strictly a function of $x$ because everywhere except at the turning points, two values of the velocity occur, differing only by sign).

Comment: Yeap, that's right, I forgot that $\pm$ in $v=±\omega\sqrt{A^2-x^2}.$